# How do we 'whitelist' our website for Facebook?

Tags: facebook, spam, unsafe

How do we 'whitelist' our website - when people click on a link to our website (www.ineed.co.uk) it comes up as 'Facebook thinks this site is unsafe ...'

Comment: try debugging your site with  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug - u can see if there s any tags that facebook do not like

Answer (score 0):

If you debug that site you can see :

```
Inferred Property   The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags. 
Inferred Property   The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

fix those tags in  the head of your website and it d be fine.